# Multi update Laravel why only my first row can updated

Tags: php, laravel

Why can only my first row be updated? In this form, loop 5 time

```
<form action="{{ route('detilpermintaan.update') }}" name="Patk" id="Patk" method="POST" style="display: inline-block;"
      class="was-validated">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
        <input type="number" name="id[]" value="{{ $b->id }}" hidden>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input"
               aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" name="satuan_permintaan[]" value="{{ $b->satuan_permintaan }}"
               min="1" max={{ $b->stok }} required>
        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">{{ $b->subsatuan_atk }}</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Blade/View**

```
@php $no = 1; @endphp
@forelse ($permintaans as $b)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $no ++ }}</td>
        <td>
            {{ $b->nama_kategori }} {{ $b->nama_atk }}
        </td>
        <td>
            <form action="{{ route('detilpermintaan.update') }}" name="Patk" id="Patk" method="POST"
                  style="display: inline-block;" class="was-validated">
                @csrf
                @method('PUT')
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                    <input type="number" name="id[]" value="{{ $b->id }}" hidden>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input"
                           aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" name="satuan_permintaan[]"
                           value="{{ $b->satuan_permintaan }}" min="1" max={{ $b->stok }} required>

                    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">{{ $b->subsatuan_atk }}</span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form action="{{ route('detilpermintaan.destroy', $b->id) }}" method="POST" style="display: inline-block;">
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <button type="submit" class="btn custom2-btn"></button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @empty
    @endforelse
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
        @if ($permintaans->isEmpty())
        @else
            <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                <h6><b> jenis barang dengan quantity sebanyak item </b></h6>
                <button type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="submitForms()"><i
                            class="bi bi-floppy2-fill"></i> Simpan
                </button>
            </div>
        @endif

        <script>
            function submitForms() {
                var forms = document.getElementsByName("Patk");
                forms.forEach(function (form) {
                    form.submit();
                });
                document.getElementById('Patk').submit();
            }
        </script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->input('id')); $i++) {
            $id = $request->id[$i];
            Detilpermintaan::where('id', $id)->update([
                'satuan_permintaan' => $request->satuan_permintaan[$i],
                'permintaan_id' => $id_permintaan,
                // Add other fields as needed
            ]);
        }

        DB::commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        // Handle the exception
        dd($e->getMessage()); // Output the error message for debugging
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Error updating records.']);
    }
    
    return redirect()->route('detilpermintaan.index');
}
```

Update data where id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple forms in your Blade view. Each form is submitted when you call `form.submit()` in `submitForms()`, resulting in multiple HTTP requests, each carrying the data of one form only. That's why only the first row is updated. To solve this, you should have only one form that wraps all your input fields and then submits that single form.

```
@php $no = 1; @endphp
<form action="{{ route('detilpermintaan.update') }}" name="Patk" id="Patk" method="POST" style="display: inline-block;" class="was-validated">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    @forelse ($permintaans as $b)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $no ++ }}</td>
            <td>
                {{ $b->nama_kategori }} {{ $b->nama_atk }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                    <input type="number" name="id[]" value="{{ $b->id }}" hidden>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" name="satuan_permintaan[]" value="{{ $b->satuan_permintaan }}" min="1" max={{ $b->stok }} required>
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">{{ $b->subsatuan_atk }}</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn custom2-btn" onclick="submitDeleteForm('deleteForm{{ $b->id }}')"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @empty
    @endforelse
    <button type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="bi bi-floppy2-fill"></i> Simpan</button>
</form>

@forelse ($permintaans as $b)
    <form action="{{ route('detilpermintaan.destroy', $b->id) }}" id="deleteForm{{ $b->id }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
    </form>
@endforelse

<script>
    function submitDeleteForm(formId) {
        document.getElementById(formId).submit();
    }
</script>
```

Remove the `submitForms()` function... you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks Karl, but how i can handel delete form?

Comment: They also have another sneaky form for deletion (now nested inside your main form). They should probably move that outside down the bottom and replaced it with a button that calls a function.